# Error touch file Linux: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, bash, filesystems, touch, ext4

I am running on a 2.6.32 kernel, ext4 filesystem, 64 bit Linux system. I have a directory whose contents are:

```
[raul.tabacu@fep-62-1 Licenta]$ ls -la
total 513
drwxr-xr-x  9 raul.tabacu studcs    573 2015-05-05 23:05 .
drwx------ 27 raul.tabacu studcs  12288 2015-05-05 22:42 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 raul.tabacu studcs     93 2014-11-08 19:26 compareResults.sh
-rwxr-x---  1 raul.tabacu studcs 165525 2015-05-05 22:37 crosspn7.dat
-rwxrwx---  1 raul.tabacu studcs 165492 2014-10-25 21:45 jkl
-rw-r--r--  1 raul.tabacu studcs    445 2015-02-05 08:15 Makefile
drwxr-xr-x  4 raul.tabacu studcs    102 2014-11-08 19:13 rezultate
drwxrwx---  2 raul.tabacu studcs    565 2015-05-05 22:56 runConfigs
-rwxr-xr-x  1 raul.tabacu studcs    287 2014-11-04 22:12 runexp.sh
drwxrwx--- 40 raul.tabacu studcs  12288 2015-04-19 15:42 Runner
....
-rw-r--r--  1 raul.tabacu studcs      0 2015-05-05 22:55 tutu.dat
```

When I try creating a new file, called `crospp.7.dat` using `touch` I get a `No such file or directory` error, but creating a file called `crosppp.7.dat` works perfectly fine.

```
[raul.tabacu@fep-62-1 Licenta]$ touch crosspp.7.dat
touch: cannot touch `crosspp.7.dat': No such file or directory
[raul.tabacu@fep-62-1 Licenta]$
```

I am sure that I have the necessary access rights, and that there's no file with that name. An important note, I think, is the following output, directory `Licenta` being the one I'm trying to create a file into.

```
[raul.tabacu@fep-62-2 ~]$ ls -ld Licenta
drwxr-xr-x 9 raul.tabacu studcs -->403<-- 2015-05-05 23:05 Licenta
[raul.tabacu@fep-62-2 ~]$ cd Licenta
[raul.tabacu@fep-62-2 Licenta]$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x 9 raul.tabacu studcs -->573<-- 2015-05-05 23:05 .
```

Does anyone have an idea what could possibly gone so wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Look for suspicious things in `stat .` or `stat file`. And is this a regular HD? If so, you could have a look at the smart output. Maybe its just about to die.

Comment: That was my initial thought. Unfortunately, I don't know the exact configuration of the HDD, 'cause the whole thing is running on a remote machine which I don't have root/setup access to. I'll come back with a `stat` output.